# The JSON from HTTP path contains neither model topology or manifest for weights

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I trained classifier using tf.keras and converted saved model from .h5 to .json using tensorflowjs_converter

```
!tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras '/content/ver1.h5' '/content/json'
```

Then I tried to load a model using

```
tf.loadLayersModel("http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json")
```

I used http-server with --cors to avoid any problems, however, I keep getting console errors with:

> http.ts:175 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The JSON from HTTP path http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json contains neither model topology nor manifest for weights.

The error comes from lines:

```
const modelTopology = modelJSON.modelTopology;
    const weightsManifest = modelJSON.weightsManifest;
    if (modelTopology == null && weightsManifest == null) {
      throw new Error(`The JSON from HTTP path ${this.path} contains neither model ` + `topology or manifest for weights.`);
    }
```

And after opening the file at http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json the manifest and model topology are there.

```
// 20221014001551
// http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json

{
  "format": "layers-model",
  "generatedBy": "keras v2.8.0",
  "convertedBy": "TensorFlow.js Converter v3.21.0",
  "modelTopology": {
    "keras_version": "2.8.0",
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "model_config": {
      "class_name": "Functional",
      "config": {
        "name": "model",
.......
```

and here:

```
"weightsManifest": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "group1-shard1of3.bin",
        "group1-shard2of3.bin",
        "group1-shard3of3.bin"
      ],
      "weights": [
        {
          "name": "dense/kernel",
........
```

I don't have any idea what's going wrong here, waiting for some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use tf.model.load instead of tf.loadLayersModel.